# How to use ternary in ng-init in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Is it possible to use ternary operator in `ng-init` in AngularJS ?

Something like : `<select ng-model="project" name="act" ng-options="act.user_id as act.user_display_name for act in actors" ng-init="isLoggedIn == true ? "" : act.user_id = credentials.user_id" ></select>`

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it's possible. Here's a very simple demo:

http://jsbin.com/wobayovi/1/edit?html,output

Comment: Hey @bencripps, thanks. Seems work :) but very touchy huh ? What means (true === true) ?

Comment: Haha I didnt mean anything by it-- I just wanted a very simple demo. True will always evaluate to true, you could change the ternary expression to anything you like.